# UIView bottom view like classic iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a problem with my project, I am at a point where i don't know how to.
My problem is with "scrolling" or gesture with `UIView`. I need to create a bottom view like classic iOS bottom function bar with animation. But my view stops at for example 100px from bottom. 
Any tutorial or help with this?

Image here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
   self.yourView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.yourView.frame.size.width, self.yourView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.yourView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 100, self.yourView.frame.size.width, self.yourView.frame.size.height);
    }];
```

Let me know if you face any difficulty in it..

Refer this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation) for more info..

Comment: Yes i know that, thank u, another question is how to create a slider, which scroll in line. Drag and drop is dragging everywhere i can , but i need only in one line , understand what i want ?

Comment: Not exactly.. Would you like to create object which can be draggable anywhere on the screen?

Comment: No , only draggable in one direction, in our case to bottom and then to middle of screen like on image.

Comment: Add Pan Gesture to your object & assign target method to it.. Apply necessary logic inside that method. For Gesture refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more